# Prevent IIS Recycling for specific change in files

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I have a column in my grid view with images of a progress bar. These images are created on each render and written to my 'write' folder.
However, after Microsft's patch KB3052480, IIS resets once files in the application's directory have been created, changed, or overwritten.
This can be changed in IIS's settings so that it never resets on update . However this means the application would need to manually be restarted when any patch is applied (not an acceptable outcome).
Is there a way to keep the setting (so that IIS still resets on updates such as changes to .dll files) but still create and write images without it resetting.
I have looked around a lot but there is not much information on this particular issue.
What I was thinking is- somehow stop monitoring changes to file right before the save takes place. And then resume monitoring again.
How would this be done, or is there another way to prevent IIS from recycling after this specific change?

Comment: The simplest solution is to include all the files beforehand rather than creating them. But we want to be able to use dynamic image creation throughout the application. So I was hoping to find out how other people have dealt with dynamic image creation when they needed to keep IIS configured to recycle upon file changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question mentioned in the comment, which I think is your real question, to prevent the app domain from recycling on file save don't put the files you are saving inside the websites' folder. Instead have it in some other path that is not part of the application.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late but if you are using asp.net framework, then you can store the "dynamic" files in App_Data, i think its a exception to the recycle rule.